# Pygame keys jam if multiple keys are pressed

Tags: python, pygame

If I press KP4, KP5 and KP1 at the same time, it never recognizes them all at the same time. Is there any way to fix that?

```
while True:
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_KP4]:
        print('4')
    if keys[pygame.K_KP5]:
        print('5')
    if keys[pygame.K_KP1]:
        print('1')
```

Explanation: The problem was that my keyboard can only handle 2 inputs from the numpad.

Comment: What exactly is your desired output?

Comment: 4-5-1-..., but I get 4-1-..., 5-1-... or 4-5-...

Comment: @StefanFörster In SO you should not add SOLVED to the title, instead mark a response as correct, if none of the current answers is your solution we invite you to post a new answer and mark it as correct after 2 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is known as [key jamming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_(key)#Key_jamming_and_ghosting). The only solution is to change the keys in your game (or to buy a gaming keyboard). For the end users it's helpful if they can assign the keys themselves (because which keys jam also depends on the brands and models of keyboards).